# no AVD Manager menu option in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, android-virtual-device

I've installed 
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Build id: 20150219-0600

There is no menu item for the AVD Manager. See links to screenshots below. The screenshot that shows the menu item is from a youtube video, which is how I discovered I was missing something. The screenshot without the menu item is from my software.

I can launch the AVD Manager from the SDK folder. I just wonder if the lack of a menu item is a symptom of a larger situation that could cause a problem later.

Anyone know why this is happening?

no AVD Manager menu item
http://www.screencast.com/t/rcp48pZB3ueE

shows menu item
http://www.screencast.com/t/agsC6dofkQpI

Comment: short n simple : if you want to work with android, and mobile apps.. use Android Studio its the best.. you can download it from here.. https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: I think I'm going to have to do that. Right now, I have a whole bunch of API files, etc. installed. Many, many files. Do I need to remove these first?

Comment: Eclipse is completely different .. even if you dont remove them.. it doesn't matter.. just download the Android Studio.. even official developer site says you should use Android Studio.. you just need to have JAVA installed on your laptop that;s it

Comment: I have Java version 8 installed. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Is adt plugins for android installed in eclipse?